Как получить массив путей к файлам?
Коллеги. Есть старая сборка не моя. Собрано на gulp v-3.9.1 && angularjs v-1.4.9, Angularjs вообще собирается через bower, в общем все старое и не пригодное.
Смысл проблемы в том, что меня попросили написать функцию для слайдера, который будет собирать все фото из определенной папки в массив. Заказчики хотят просто менять или добавлять папки с фото и получать массив путей к этим картинкам. (Чтобы не формировать массив картинок в ручную , их более 60).
У меня была подобная задача тоже на angularjs v-1.8.2 сборка webpack-5
у меня даже был вопрос на эту тему и решение было таковым
const importImg = r => r.keys().forEach((s) => [].push(s));
console.log(importImg(require.context("../../../../img/slider/", true, /\.svg$/)));

Забыл отметить, что данная функция require.context(... в данной сборке не работает
Подскажите как реализовать данную задачу на клиенте?  Единственное, что придумал, это формировать массив на сервере и отправить на клиент. (это уже готово и работает).
Просто стало интересно можно ли это сделать только на клиенте?

Пожалуйста уточните заголовок вопроса - "Как получить массив путей к файлам в старом Angularjs на клиенте?". А то сейчас он черезчур широк )

@Kromster, а при чём тут ангуляр? Тут скорее галп - он же при сборке получает, а ангуляр вообще не при делах.

Так я кам и предлагаю вопросу дать название отражающее правильный стек, чтобы не надо было в него заходить и узнавать что это BAT или Excel или Angular или докер или еще что )

в порядке бреда: у nginx есть autoindex, включить отдачу именно того каталога в формате json https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_format, сделать запрос на сервер для получения списка файлов )

Насколько я понял, при изменении картинок пересобирается весь проект?
Решение спорное, но под него легко намутить костыль: перед сборкой выполняем команду
node -e "fs.writeFileSync('files.js', 'const files = ' + JSON.stringify(fs.readdirSync('.'), null, 2), 'utf8')"

а уже этот файл используем коде приложения (можно вместо глобальной константы сделать ангулярную или вообще намотать что угодно вокруг массива).
Проблема:
Если картинки могут добавлять разные люди, в этом файле могут возникать конфликты.
Возможные решения:

добавить его в .gitignore
при возникновении конфликтов спокойно аппрувить любой и перегенерировать
научить гит самостоятельно перегенерировать файл вместо мёрджа


Qwertiy, благодарю, что отозвался, но легче это реализовать через сервер (как это уже реализовано).  Я понимаю, что это надо gulp чужой исправлять, не люблю в чужом коде ковыряться... ))))).

@Air, какое отношение gulp имеет к серверу?

Qwertiy, к серверу ни какого, естественно .   Я просто название  файлов  получаю с сервера.
